# How do I change display name for app in Facebook app install ads?

Tags: facebook

See the image below.  How do I change the name of the app so that it says "Vinus - Australian Wine App".

I changed the display name in the developers dashboard and re-submitted the app for review.  Facebook changed the display name (the app in the dashboard is now called "Vinus - Australian Wine App", but the name of the app in app install ads is still just Vinus.

I tried creating a fresh new app install ad, but the app is still called just "Vinus" in app install ads.

Any help greatly appreciated.

[image: Display name]

Comment: I think changing the name of the app itself in the App Store will solve this.  Will report back, may take a while as our next deployment isn't for a few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it out - you need to change the name of the actual app.  I.e. release a new version with the the app name changed, in my instance to "Vinus Wine Discovery App".

That seemed to work (after a delay of about a week [I think] after new version released on App Store).

Comment: So it's the AppStore name that appears there?

Comment: Two years ago that's how it worked but I haven't checked up on this recently.